# How do I add these windows in wpf?

Tags: wpf

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91AL9.png)

How do I add these windows in wpf?

It hasn't been long since I started wpf and I don't know what functions are there.

I understand that most tools are only used in windows.

Comment: In addition to the wpf created, it's about creating a window at a particular location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image you posted shows what's called a "Toast Notification".

According to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/send-local-toast?tabs=uwp),

1. Install the nuget package called `Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications`.
2. Initialize a new ToastContentBuilder() and show the toast notification as follows -

```
new ToastContentBuilder()
    .AddInlineImage(new Uri("Your Image location"))
    .AddAppLogoOverride(new Uri("Your Image location"), ToastGenericAppLogoCrop.Circle)
    .Show();
```

This notification will show up as any other app notification on windows on the side and as far as I know, you cannot customize the location of the default toast notification. In that case, show another Window on screen using `.Show()` in place of a notification.